# session attributes getting replicated for different user sessions

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am building an online hotel reservation system. for that I am using a reservation cart in which I keep track of rooms added by the user. When I am adding some rooms in a browser login in with user1 , now when I log in with some other browser with user2 and add some other rooms in the cart. Now when I try to add another room in cart of user1 ,  the existing cart of user1 gets replaced by the cart values of user2.  I am maintaining different sessions for each user but the cart attribute is getting same for all the sessions . I am currently working on local host. please help

this is how I am adding values to rbList and setting the session attribute.

```
if(request.getParameter("button").equals("addRoom"))
        {   // System.out.println("******************inside addRoom*****************");
            if(session!=null)
            {   

                availableRooms = (ArrayList<HotelBean>)session.getAttribute("availableRooms");

                int addPos = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("roomPosition"));
                rb = availableRooms.get(addPos);
                String roomID = rb.getRoomId();
                HoteDAO hd = new HoteDAO();
                boolean available = hd.isAvailable(roomID);
                if(available){
                    if((ArrayList<HotelBean>)session.getAttribute("ReservationCart") == null){
                        rbList = new ArrayList<HotelBean>();
                    }
                    if(rbList == null){
                        rbList = new ArrayList<HotelBean>();
                    }
                    rbList.add(rb);
                    for(HotelBean room : rbList){
                        System.out.println(room.getRoomId());
                    }
                    session.setAttribute("ReservationCart",rbList);
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/AvailableRooms.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request,response);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry the room is not available now");
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/AvailableRooms.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request,response);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: From what you describe it seems that you only have one instance of cart, where do you save the customer carts?

Comment: @Dimitris How do I define different carts for different customers . I am just defining the cart (ArrayList) in my servlet code once as class variable. Won't it create different instance for each session ?

Comment: It should, although I would feel much safer putting it in an actual database, sessions can be dropped. I just don't see where you declared your variable rblist, an obvious way to get your error would be if you made a bean out of it.

Comment: [ . package main.controller;

public class HotelReservationContoller extends HttpServlet {
 ArrayList<HotelBean> rbList=new ArrayList<HotelBean>();
 ArrayList<HotelBean>availableRooms = new ArrayList<HotelBean>();
       public HotelReservationContoller() {
        super();
    }  ] .    This where I have defined the list. the doPost method shared above is within this class

Comment: Have you made a bean for HotelReservationContoller?

Comment: I am not using spring. I am using jsp and with jsp I have created a form which I have linked to this controller using action

Comment: You must have instantiated somewhere the controller. Or do you create a new one every time you need it?

Comment: There is **only one** instance of the servlet class for the whole web application, i.e. if you define a class variable, it is common for the whole web app. Define it within the `doGet` (or `doPost`) method and get it from the session, if you want to manipulate it.

Comment: I am not instantiating the controller anywhere. I am simply using buttons inside my form in different jsp pages, all action set to HotelReservationContoller and I have different methods defined within this controller

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment is the answer to your problem. You instantiate the rbList in a class that has only one instance across your web application. Hence you only have only one rbList accross all customers and that causes your problem. 
Although I do not have a very clear picture of how your rbList work, I am confident that each customer should have their own unique rbList or at least their own cart.

Also, declaring the customer cart in a controller seems like a poor design choice.

The way that I would go about your problem would be create a separate CartModel class that contains everything cart related.

Create a one to one or one to many relationship from your CustomerModel to your CartModel.

Preferably save the CartModel(s) to your database or at session if your prefer to go with this design.

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I am new to java . I will try to improve my model . BTW I made some changes in the code, earlier I was using different servlets for Login/Logout/SignUP and for all other functionalities I was using  HotelReservationContoller. after changing what I did is I added all the codes of these diff controllers in HotelReservationController and the problem got resolved.